# How to create custom full screen modal in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I want to create custom Full screen Loader component in Ionic2. But my modal div do not cover the header/navbar area. I want it to be like Ionic LoadingComponent covering everything in my app and also have my template variable. Please have a look at image.

[image]

My modal css is

```
#modal{
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  background: red;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
}
```

Please help.

EDIT
My ModalPage has navbar

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar primary>
    <button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Hello Ionic</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

EDIT

I found a workaround for this. I just use Ionic2 Popover, Popover gives 100% width+height, full screen. I called the modal popover on button click and dismiss it on 100% download.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that style rule to make the modal be fullscreen. Please take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RjXL7M?p=preview).

Like you can se there, the `HomePage` contains a navbar, but the `ModalPage` html code is just

```
<ion-content></ion-content>
```

With that, and just changing the `background-color`

```
ion-page.modal-page ion-content {
  background-color: red;
}
```

The modal should be fullscreen, without showing a navbar.

Comment: My ModalPage also has a navbar I have edited my question.

Comment: Ok, but why are you adding a navbar in the html code if you don't want to show it then?

Comment: Normally navbar will be present on the page, when I click a button I want a modal window to cover the whole screen and start some download and show % download in it, and when that download finish the modal will disappear and normal page with navbar shown. I cant use default IonicLoader for this, as it does not support template variables.

Comment: I understand, but the navbar is still not required in the `ModalPage`. After the download is finished, you could just dismiss the modal and push a new Page with a navbar.

Comment: Where you able to fix this issue?

Comment: I used Ionic2 popover, & in popover page I shows download, it has width  + height 100%, full screen, sadly Ionic do not provide that functionality in by default

Comment: Great! If you don't mind, please add that to the OP so other SO users with the same issue could find the answer easier :)